# Install Qt3 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, qt3

I'm try to use some AAM tools which require the Qt3.
I try to run `apt-get install libqt3-mt` but got the error information below:

> Package libqt3-mt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libqt3-mt' has no installation candidate

Is there anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a solution (package already prepared or compiled)?

Comment: You should post this thread into AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they took it out of the repo for some reason but you can find the libqt3-mt package at the following [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/libqt3-mt/download).